# Jasperreports print subreport horizontal

Tags: jasper-reports

In my master report i have an SQL query that retrive multiple row.

```
SELECT id FROM person
```

Then i send this id to the subReport to retrive the name of this person.

```
SELECT name FROM person WHERE id =  $P{id}
```

In my subReport i have a static label & field text.

[image: my subREport content]

Everything work fine but when i run this example the name of person show vertically.

```
name1:   Jack
name2:   Tom
name3:   Jerry
name4 : ............ ect
```

What i want that the list of name show horizentally. Like this:

```
name1:    Jack     name2:     Tom      name3:   Jerry     name4:...... ect
```

The problem that i don't know the number of rows so i can not divide the page (set Columns as specific number).
Any help please